# Couldn't find script callback function inside object

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, oauth, callback

I use [OAuth library](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) from Google in order to set connection with Spotify. There is a problem. When `createService()` and `authCallback()` is part of `auth` object, raised error:

> Couldn't find script function: `authCallback()`

Why is the callback function not visible inside the auth object?

The code for this case:

```
function doGet() {
    if (auth.hasAccess()) {
        main();
    } else {
        return auth.createFlow();
    }
}

const auth = (function () {
    const CLIENT_ID = '...';
    const CLIENT_SECRET = '...';

    const _service = createService();

    function createService() {
        return OAuth2.createService('spotify')
            .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize')
            .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token')
            .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
            .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
            .setCallbackFunction('authCallback') // set callback
            .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
            .setScope('playlist-read-private playlist-modify-private playlist-modify-public user-library-read')
            .setParam('response_type', 'code')
            .setParam('redirect_uri', getRedirectUri());
    }

    function authCallback(request) {
        let isAuthorized = _service.handleCallback(request);
        if (isAuthorized) {
            return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success! You can close this tab.');
        } else {
            return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied. You can close this tab');
        }
    }

    ...

    return {
        hasAccess: hasAccess,
        getAccessToken: getAccessToken,
        createFlow: createFlow,
    };
})();
```

But if do this without `auth` object, no error and success callback:

```
function createService() {
    return OAuth2.createService('spotify')
        .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
        // ...
}

function authCallback(request) {
    // ...
}
```

I can do this, but then it makes no sense to hide implementation details in the `auth` object:

```
const auth = (function () {
    function createService() {
        return OAuth2.createService('spotify')
            .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
            // ...
    }

    function authCallback(request) {
        // ...
    }

    return {
        // ...
        authCallback: authCallback,
    };
})();

function authCallback(request) {
    return auth.authCallback(request);
}

function doGet() {
    if (auth.hasAccess()) {
        main();
    } else {
        return auth.createFlow();
    }
}
```

## Full code with error

```
function doGet() {
    if (auth.hasAccess()) {
        main();
    } else {
        return auth.createFlow();
    }
}

const auth = (function () {
    const CLIENT_ID = '...';
    const CLIENT_SECRET = '...';

    const _service = createService();

    function createService() {
        return OAuth2.createService('spotify')
            .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize')
            .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token')
            .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
            .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
            .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
            .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
            .setScope('playlist-read-private playlist-modify-private playlist-modify-public user-library-read')
            .setParam('response_type', 'code')
            .setParam('redirect_uri', getRedirectUri());
    }

    function authCallback(request) {
        let isAuthorized = _service.handleCallback(request);
        if (isAuthorized) {
            return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success! You can close this tab.');
        } else {
            return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied. You can close this tab');
        }
    }

    function getRedirectUri() {
        let scriptId = encodeURIComponent(ScriptApp.getScriptId());
        let template = 'https://script.google.com/macros/d/%s/usercallback';
        return Utilities.formatString(template, scriptId);
    }

    function hasAccess() {
        return _service.hasAccess();
    }

    function getAccessToken() {
        return _service.getAccessToken();
    }

    function createFlow() {
        let template = '<a href="%s" target="_blank">Authorize</a>';
        let html = Utilities.formatString(template, _service.getAuthorizationUrl());
        return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
    }

    return {
        hasAccess: hasAccess,
        getAccessToken: getAccessToken,
        createFlow: createFlow,
    };
})();
```

Comment: If you don't expose `authCallback` in your `IIFE`, how would the caller be able to invoke it?

Comment: Who exactly are you trying to hide it from?

Comment: What are the benefits that you are looking for to declare `authCallback` inside an object instead of doing this at the global scope?

Comment: @Rubén encapsulation

Comment: [You can't have your cake and eat it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_can%27t_have_your_cake_and_eat_it) :D Please read [Object-oriented JavaScript for beginners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object-oriented_JS)

Comment: which line causes the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value you pass into `setCallbackFunction()` actually gets passed into the [`StateTokenBuilder.withMethod()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/state-token-builder#withMethod(String)) method, which does not require the argument to be available in the global scope.  But that means you need to pass it the string 'auth.authCallback'. Simply passing it 'authCallback' won't work because there is no function in the global scope with that name.

So then it also means that you need to expose `authCallback` in your return statement so that it becomes available in the global scope as `auth.authCallback`.

```
const auth = (function () {
    const CLIENT_ID = '...';
    const CLIENT_SECRET = '...';

    const _service = createService();

    function createService() {
        return OAuth2.createService('spotify')
            .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize')
            .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token')
            .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
            .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
            .setCallbackFunction('auth.authCallback') // Use correct method name
            .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
            .setScope('playlist-read-private playlist-modify-private playlist-modify-public user-library-read')
            .setParam('response_type', 'code')
            .setParam('redirect_uri', getRedirectUri());
    }

    function authCallback(request) {
        let isAuthorized = _service.handleCallback(request);
        if (isAuthorized) {
            return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success! You can close this tab.');
        } else {
            return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied. You can close this tab');
        }
    }

    function getRedirectUri() {
        let scriptId = encodeURIComponent(ScriptApp.getScriptId());
        let template = 'https://script.google.com/macros/d/%s/usercallback';
        return Utilities.formatString(template, scriptId);
    }

    function hasAccess() {
        return _service.hasAccess();
    }

    function getAccessToken() {
        return _service.getAccessToken();
    }

    function createFlow() {
        let template = '<a href="%s" target="_blank">Authorize</a>';
        let html = Utilities.formatString(template, _service.getAuthorizationUrl());
        return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
    }

    return {
        hasAccess: hasAccess,
        getAccessToken: getAccessToken,
        createFlow: createFlow,
        authCallback: authCallback // Expose the method
    };
})();
```

Just to help clarify the purpose of `authCallback()`, try renaming it to something like `displayAuthSuccessOrFailure()`. All it's doing is presenting a success or failure message to the end user. This may alter how you think about its exposure/encapsulation.